# Add new column to Deedle Frame

Tags: c#, deedle

I want to add column with data to a deedle dataframe.
I'm doing it this way, and it works, but I believe there should be a better way ?

```
void addTrendValues(Frame<int, string> df){

    List<double> trend_val = new List<double>();      

    df.FillMissing(0);
    List<int> indexes= new List<int>();
    for(int i =0; i<1000;i++){
        double trendpips = getPipsTilNextTrend(df,i);           
        trend_val.Add(trendpips);     
        indexes.Add(i);
        if(i% 10000 == 0) { Console.WriteLine(i) ;}            
    }


    df.AddColumn("trend_val",new Series<int, double>(indexes.ToArray(),trend_val.ToArray()));

}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` in some way, then you can use the `ToSeries` extension method provided by Deedle. The following does that quite nicely using LINQ (but it also removes the printing, which you might want to recover).

```
var newSeries = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(i =>
    KeyValue.Create(i, getPipsTilNextTrend(df, i))).ToSeries();
df.AddColumn("trend_val", newSeries);
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try !